# RegExp to match a URL

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Scripts, I'm trying to match a URL using RegExp using the following function.

```
function testRegex(){
  var str = "href='https://sites.google.com/a/domain.com/image-store/images/Image1.jpg?attredirects=0'";
  var regex = new RegExp('http[:a-zA-Z\.\/\-_]{0,100}Image1.jpg', 'gi');
  str = str.replace(regex,"new_url");
  Logger.log(str);
}
```

When I input the same regexp and string into the regular expression tester at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html , **it works**. However, it doesn't work in Google Apps Scripts.

Any ideas why?

EDIT:
I figured the problem is with the underscore. Replacing with \w helps. So, when I replace the Regex with

```
https[\.a-zA-Z0-9\/+:\w-]{0,100}Image1.jpg
```

IT WORKS.

But, it still doesn't match an underscore. For example, it doesn't work with the following  the URL

```
https://sites.google.com/a/domain.com/image-store/_/rsrc/1351707816362/images/Image1.jpg
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: If you use the same code in Google Apps Script, the log window shows the original string and doesn't replace it with "new_url"

Comment: I notice that your regex does not specify a number range in the character class. Is it possible that your *real* input string contains a number somewhere?

Comment: Although the real string contains a number, this one fails too, unfortunately. In fact, I've put 0-9 and it doesn't help much

Comment: Well, why would it match an underscore? You didn't specify one. See my edited answer below.

Comment: In my first regex, I did specify the underscore. In the second one, I specified \w which is supposed to match an underscore ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp )

Comment: var regex = new RegExp('http[:a-zA-Z\.\/+\-_]{1,100}Image1.jpg', 'gi');   FYI I tried your original match with the + addition as above and I found that this underscore did match, as per your edit revision.  I.e. https://sites.google.com/a/domain.com/image-store/_/rsrc/1351707816362/images/Image1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't debug your code, but I tried it on repl.it and verified that it is not correct in Chrome's V8 JavaScript either. I suspect there is a bug here that is unrelated to Apps Script.

EDIT: This works:

```
function testRegex(){
  var str = "href='https://sites.google.com/a/domain.com/image-store/_/rsrc/1351707816362/images/Image1.jpg'";
  var regex = new RegExp('https[\.a-zA-Z0-9\/+:\w_-]{0,100}Image1.jpg', 'gi');
  str = str.replace(regex,"new_url");
  Logger.log(str);
}
```

It didn't match underscores because you didn't specify an underscore in the character class.

Comment: Thanks, Corey. I figured the problem is with the underscore. I've made edits to the question with more info.

Comment: Corey, please see the edit with the new regex and the new URL which doesn't work even with repl.it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a + after the slash might do it:

```
function testRegex(){
  var str = "href='https://sites.google.com/a/domain.com/image-store/images/Image1.jpg?attredirects=0'";
  var regex = new RegExp('http[:a-zA-Z\.\/+\-_]{1,100}Image1.jpg', 'gi');
  str = str.replace(regex,"new_url");
  Logger.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Also (+David and +Srik), is it necessary to have all the escape backslashes inside the character class? It seems to work without them.

Comment: Hello Adam. I don't know the answer to either! I just had a lucky hunch.  I just tried without backslashes as you had intimated, and confirm it works.  Magic?

Comment: David, Thanks. I did more debugging and figured the problem was with the underscore. I replaced it with \w and I was able to match the URL.
However, the same thing fails for a new URL with an underscore. I'll edit the question with the details